# WebLogic Foreign JNDI Provider names

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

When I try to create a Foreign JNDI datasource using the same JNDI name for Local & Remote Links, I get a Stackoverflow exception for a recursive call:

Probably this is an expected behavior, but I couldn't verify it.

Thus, is it mandatory to have different JNDI names for Local&Remote ?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.isAccessAllowed(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.WLSAuthorizationServiceWrapper.isAccessAllowed(WLSAuthorizationServiceWrapper.java:158)
    at weblogic.security.service.AuthorizationManager.isAccessAllowed(AuthorizationManager.java:316)
    at weblogic.security.service.AuthorizationManager.isAccessAllowed(AuthorizationManager.java:379)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.checkPermission(ServerNamingNode.java:452)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.checkLookup(ServerNamingNode.java:434)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:185)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:210)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ForeignOpaqueReference.getReferent(ForeignOpaqueReference.java:74)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLNamingManager.getObjectInstance(WLNamingManager.java:92)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.resolveObject(ServerNamingNode.java:388)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.resolveObject(BasicNamingNode.java:886)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:219)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:224)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ForeignOpaqueReference.getReferent(ForeignOpaqueReference.java:74)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLNamingManager.getObjectInstance(WLNamingManager.java:92)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.resolveObject(ServerNamingNode.java:388)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.resolveObject(BasicNamingNode.java:886)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:219)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:224)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
```

Comment: Does it work when you specify different names ? I would think the two JNDI names are separate.

Comment: yes, it works when they are different

Answer (score 0):

JNDI names are :

```
unique, people-friendly names
```

Please refer to Oracle's documentation for any further details :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19747-01/819-0076/jndi.html

Comment: but this is not an issue about naming JNDI resources, but sharing same name between two different Managed Servers. Being different JNDI tree and making a reference form local to remote JNDI name, the question if is it possible to have the same name in each tree